# Is using [(ngModel)] in reactive forms bad practice?

Tags: forms, angular

I'm starting to use model based forms in my angular App. So far I have been suing template based forms and I bind my data using `[(ngModel)]`.

I noticed that using `[(ngModel)]` in reactive forms is possible, but I've been reading on stack that it's a bad practice, but I can't find (or missed) anything about this in the docs.

Is it true that you should avoid using when you are working with reactive forms? If so, what would be the correct way to bind data to an input?

Right now I do something like this:

**My component:**

```
this.assignForm = this.fb.group({
    "balance": [null, Validators.required]
});
```

**My Template**

```
<input type="text" formControlName="balance" [(ngModel)]="myData.Balance" />
```

Comment: Short answer: Don't mix it.

Comment: @ManishJain Why not?

Comment: Good question, unless you manually bind variable to every new input variable,For "reactive form" requires you to update via API.   "reactive form" is not that reactive compare to ngmodel in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title and question completely mix up model based and reactive, where your code uses them both combined. Using both combined results in absolutely no guarantee that the value you see and the value your form controller contains are equal. Just do not do it.

The correct way would be:

```
this.assignForm = this.fb.group({
    "balance": [myData.Balance, Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: The question is not mixed-up: the author is asking about whether this combination is possible. "*Using both combined results in absolutely no guarantee that the value you see and the value your form controller contains are equal*" > this seems to be the key part of your answer; can you expand upon it?

Comment: If you update your model, your input element value will change with it, but the changed event is not triggered; your form controller contains the old value. If you update your value setting the controller value; your model has not changed and will either change the value displayed right back, or your model just isn't changed.

Answer (score 4):

Every HTML input element is wrapped by an angular class called `FormControl`.  `FormBuilder` creates the `FormControl`s explicitly.  Putting `NgModel` on a element will *also* create a `FormControl`.

In your example, you have two `FormControl` objects for the same element.

Assuming they don't fail due to name clash (like `<input name="myname" formControlName="myname" [(ngModel)]="model.prop" />` would register myname with the `FormGroup` twice), then you might get different answers on `valid/invalid/touched/dirty` depending on which one was queried.